# CSS div layout positioning

Tags: html, css

I want to draw 4 divs according to the following picture.

[image]

But instead I'm getting this.

[image]

Below is my html. The wrapping div's position is set to relative and the containing div's to absolute. But, they are all stacked up on one another. Thank you.

```css
 #container{
    position: relative;
   }
   .blocks{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
   }
   #1{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto auto;
   }
   #2{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
   }
   #3{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
   }
   #4{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto auto;
    bottom: 20px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
 <body>
      <div id="container">
  <div class="blocks" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="blocks" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="blocks" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="blocks" id="4">4</div>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo in `margin: auto audio;`

Comment: Thanks  j08691. I corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Ids aren't allowed to begin with a number so you're 1,2,3 etc. aren't being read at all.

2) You spelled height wrong in your .blocks class

3) You don't really need absolute positioning to use floats, so the only element you might need it on it #4, I would just use margin to give this div space and make it appear below the other divs.

I suggest you try the following:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
.blocks {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
#a1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#a2 {
  float: left;
}
#a3 {
  float: right;
}
#a4 {
  margin: 200px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="blocks" id="a1">1</div>
  <div class="blocks" id="a2">2</div>
  <div class="blocks" id="a3">3</div>
  <div class="blocks" id="a4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
   position: relative;
 }
 
 .blocks {
   width: 200px;
   hight: 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
 }
 
 #first {
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 #second {
   float: left;
 }
 
 #third {
   float: right;
 }
 
 #fourth {
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 .clearfix:after {
   display: block;
   content: " ";
   clear: both;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="blocks" id="first">1</div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="blocks" id="second">2</div>
    <div class="blocks" id="third">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocks" id="fourth">4</div>
</div>
```

here I edited your code to achieve your purpose. you dont need position absolute here, everything could be handled with floats, also `id='1'` will not work because ids can't start with the number

Comment: Post your code in your question. If codepen is done/gone/blocked your answer loses all value

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is help full.https://jsfiddle.net/AwadheshVerma/9wLcLgjc/

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="blocks" id="id1">1</div>
   <div class="blocks" id="id2">2</div>
   <div class="blocks" id="id3">3</div>
   <div class="blocks" id="id4">4</div>
</div>

      #container {
      position: relative;
      height: 400px;
      z-index: 1;
  }
  #container:after, #container:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  #container:after {
    top: 150px;
    left:0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  }
  #container:before {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    bottom:0;
  }
  .blocks {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      background:#ddd;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 5;
  }
  #id1 {
      margin: 0 auto;
      top:0;
  }
  #id2 {
      top: 100px;
  }
  #id3 {
      top: 100px;
      right: 0;
      left: initial;
  }
  #id4 {
      margin: 0 auto;
      bottom: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can add something like this
https://jsfiddle.net/

```
 #container {
   position: relative;
 }
 .blocks {
   width: 200px;
   hight: 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
 }

 #first {
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #second {
  float: left;
 }

 #third {
  float: right;
 }

   #fourth {
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .clearfix:after {
   display: block;
   content: " ";
   clear: both;
  }

<div id="container">
  <div class="blocks" id="first">1</div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="blocks" id="second">2</div>
    <div class="blocks" id="third">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocks" id="fourth">4</div>
 </div>
```